# How do I change type int to 'a type? OCaml (Towers of Hanoi)

Tags: ocaml, towers-of-hanoi

I am a newbie at OCaml. I wrote this code about the towers of Hanoi.

```
let rec hanoi (a,b,c) n =
    if n <> 0 then begin
        hanoi (a,c,b) (pred n);
        Printf.printf "%i %i\n" a b;
       hanoi (c,b,a) (pred n) 
  end;;
```

I print: a=origin tower and b=destination tower.

I would like to do this:

```
hanoi : 'a * 'a * 'a ­> int ­> ('a * 'a) list
```

How can i change int type to 'a type? Is there any way of writing 'a type? Should I use List.append to add a ('a list)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the function you really want :)

`let rec hanoi_list n (d,a,i) =
  match n with
  |0 -> []
  |1 -> [ (d, a) ] 
  |_ -> hanoi_list (n-1) (d,i,a) @ hanoi_list 1 (d,a,i) @ hanoi_list (n-1) (i,a,d);;`

Hope you will understand it :p

Comment: typed : val hanoi_list : int -> 'a * 'a * 'a -> ('a * 'a) list = <fun>

Comment: I dont get it, what is the meaning of "d", "a" and "i". What if you want to move to the third tower and not to the second, what should you change?

Comment: d = departure, a = arrival and c = intermediate. If you use 1,2,3 to represent the tower, then moving all from first tower to 3rd will give hanoi_list 3 (1,3,2). You just have to change the parameters when you call the function.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting `int` as the type of `n` is because of the expressions `n <> 0` and `pred n`. Both of these require `n` to be an `int`. If you want `n` to be any type at all, you need polymorphic replacements for these two expressions. One possibility is to pass in a function that tests for completion and a function that decrements the value in some way.

The reason you're getting `int` for the types of `a`, `b`, and `c` is the expression `Printf.printf "%i %i\n" a b`, which requires them to be ints. Again you can pass in a function to print your values.

You then have the problem of writing these functions for various types.

You also say that you want to return a list of moves rather than printing them. This is a separate problem. The short answer is that you can pass the accumulated list as another parameter of the function and return it at the end.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, then your problem is that the inferred type of your function is

```
(int * int * int) -> int -> unit
```

Where you want it to be

```
('a * 'a * 'a) -> int -> ('a * 'a) list
```

The type of pegs is constrained to be `int`, because you are printing them, and `printf "%i" a` is defined only if `a` is of type `int`. The return value type is `unit`, because your function is not producing a tower, but just prints it.